# How to prevent citation in list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, citing, lstlisting

I want my citations in order of appearance in the main text not including the table of algorithms.

I had the same problem with my images. There I could solve it by providing an alternative text for the ToC.

That works for my images

```latex
\caption[Text for ToC without citation]{Text for the actual image with \cite{Newman2015}}
```

That's how i include my algorithms:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Text for listing with \cite{MQTT311}}, label={lst:mqtt_topics}]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want something like that for my algorithms

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Text for ToC without citation]Text for listing with \cite{MQTT311}}, label={lst:mqtt_topics}]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Is there a way to provide kind of an alternative text for the lstlisting command?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have you tried what you suggest in your latest code block? (It works.)

Comment: God, I used caption=[something]{somthing with \citation{MQTT311}}, when i tried this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont know. Should i delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Torbjørn T already mentioned thats what works:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Text for ToC without citation]Text for listing with \cite{MQTT311}}, label={lst:mqtt_topics}]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```